Why does Stack Overflow always show me a prompt to vote like I am a completely new user?
Why do I always see this prompt at the top of the screen as if I am a new user? I don't want to close this every day so I can see the question clearly, especially when I upvote questions and answers.

Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.


Do you have any plugins, etc. on your browser?

Do you see this message more than once every 48 hours per site? If so, that sounds like a bug.

I have plugins.

@NickODell, about 6-7 years when I started using SE, I didn't get this banner. I have noticed some time ago and now it just feels like a pain. I didn't know this was a think 12 years ago.

Here's the criteria over on MSE: Disable "don't forget to vote" message, and a related question here on MSO: Request reduced instances of displaying the "Don't forget to upvote the question and the answers" overlay for users with sufficiently high rep

Hm. I have seen it from time to time, but certainly not daily. It has nothing to do with if you're new or not, for me it tends to appear when I only consecutively vote on answers and never the questions.

I usually upvote the answer then question and then bookmark the question for reading later. I can't always read all the answers at that moment so I need the bookmarks. This pattern hasn't changed. I could be upvoting answers first before questions though.
